# Ubuntu touch: who decides to upgrade? And when?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, phone

There are several possibilities to use "Ubuntu touch" like "[the official phones](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/devices)" or to install an image yourself, eg. on the Nexus 4. Who decides to **update the OS**?

When I check for updates it sometimes has updates for individual apps, but it has been a while for the OS itself. Now I have "Ubuntu 15.04 (r4)" (last updated 26/07/15), but ["Ubuntu Touch OTA-5" is available for a couple of weeks](http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-touch-ota-5-to-land-on-bq-aquaris-devices-first-meizu-mx4-users-must-wait-487255.shtml). Who will offer me OTA-5 for my BQ Aquaris E5 HD? Is it BQ who decides? Is it Canonical? Can I do it myself (are chances bigger I will have a bricked phone)?

**Updates of drivers** are a different issue I guess: is it Canonical or BQ who will offer me updates?

And what about **future versions**, eg. Ubuntu Touch 15.10/16.04 LTS. Will I be able to install it on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the Ubuntu desktop OS (or any desktop Linux distribution)? Ubuntu touch uses the same approach.

Canonical has a repository where they publish updates to the OS image (drivers are included in the image). The phone checks the repository and says that an update is available. User chooses when to download it and when to install it.

Updates to future versions are like regular updates. It was already updated from 14.10 to 15.04.

Also, the Ubuntu touch repository has multiple channels. So, user can switch to a 'devel' channel and receive OS updates that are less tested, but more recent.